# Angularjs is not retrieving json from php in phonegap project when i installed new fresh window

Tags: angularjs, json, cordova

Angularjs is not retrieving json from php in phonegap project after i installed a new fresh window

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't run on Cordova/PhoneGap, you need to use a Web server and check that you have **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** policies enabled in your header for queries  outside your domain. Also if you developing Android, use the usb debugging tools to see the errors generated straight into chrome

If you developing in iOS, my condolences....

```
var headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"};
                    $http({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: url,
                        headers:headers,
                        data: data
                    })
```